# Subsonic postgreSQL Template

Tags: postgresql, subsonic

I am new to Subsonic and would like to try Subsonic 3 with postgreSQL.  Are there any templates available for postgreSQL?  The download includes templates for mySQL and SQL Server only.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a postgreSQL script in one of the folders in [the SubSonic 3.0 Templates project](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master), but I don't see a postgreSQL ttinclude file yet.

I imagine you can watch that space for one to show up, or contribute one yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know T4 at all yet. Suppose now is a good time to learn! As always, time is an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support postgres yet.